# XmlEntries to single CosmosDB entries with Azure Function

Tags: xml, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

### Hello,

I have an Azure Function with an EventHub Trigger

```
{
"bindings": [
{
  "type": "eventHubTrigger",
  "name": "myIoTHubMessage",
  "direction": "in",
  "eventHubName": "samples-workitems",
  "connection": "dorneriot_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB",
  "consumerGroup": "$Default"
},
{
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "name": "outputDocument",
  "databaseName": "outDatabase",
  "collectionName": "someName",
  "createIfNotExists": true,
  "connectionStringSetting": "someName_DOCUMENTDB",
  "direction": "out"
}
]
}
```

This receives a Json String with I convert to XML.

With this Code I save all Nodes in *one single entity* in CosmosDB:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, out object outputDocument, 
ILogger log)
{
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

if(myIoTHubMessage.Contains("Root"))
{
    output.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><text>" + 
    myIoTHubMessage + "</text>");
}


string returnstring = output.ToString();
    if(returnstring.Contains("xml"))
    {
        XmlDocument returnXml = new XmlDocument();
        returnXml.LoadXml(returnstring);
        outputDocument = new 
        {
        returnXml
        };
    }
    else
    {
        outputDocument = new
        {
            myIoTHubMessage
        };
    }
```

**But** I want to save the **separate Nodes** as single entities to a Cosmos DB.
Is it even possible and how do I do this.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write multiple documents using `IAsyncCollector()`

```
[FunctionName("WriteDocsIAsyncCollector")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger("youreh")] string message,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "ToDoItems",
            collectionName: "Items",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]
            IAsyncCollector<ToDoItem> outItems,
        ILogger log)
    {


        foreach (*/ iterate through your xml nodes/*)
        {

            await outItems.AddAsync(node);
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#queue-trigger-write-docs-using-iasynccollector-c